# Not injected bean in class that extends abstract class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I have trouble with initializing bean and injecting JPA repository into one particular bean. No idea why it doesn't work...

There is a `interface` defining key service:

```
public interface KeyService {
    Store getKeyStore();
    Store getTrustStore();
}
```

and `abstract` class that implements this interface:

```
public abstract class DefaultKeyService implements KeyService {

        abstract KeyRecord loadKeyStore();
        abstract KeyRecord loadTrustStore();

    /* rest omitted... */

        }
```

and base `class` that extends abstract class:

```
@Service
           public class DatabaseKeyService extends DefaultKeyService {

            @Autowired
                private KeyRecordRepository keyRecordRepository;

    @Override
        protected KeyRecord loadKeyStore() {
            return extract(keyRecordRepository.findKeyStore());
        }

        @Override
        protected KeyRecord loadTrustStore() {
            return extract(keyRecordRepository.findTrustStore());
        }

        /* rest omitted... */

            }
```

And `bean` initialization:

```
@Bean
    public KeyService keyService() {
        return new DatabaseKeyService();
    }
```

This is a `KeyRecordRepository` repository:

```
public interface KeyRecordRepository extends Repository<KeyRecord, Long> {

    KeyRecord save(KeyRecord keyRecord);

    @Query("SELECT t FROM KeyRecord t WHERE key_type = 'KEY_STORE' AND is_active = TRUE")
    Iterable<KeyRecord> findKeyStore();

    @Query("SELECT t FROM KeyRecord t WHERE key_type = 'TRUST_STORE' AND is_active = TRUE")
    Iterable<KeyRecord> findTrustStore();

    KeyRecord findById(long id);
}
```

**Question**: is there some reason why `keyRecordRepository` in `DatabaseKeyService` class is still null? Really I have no idea why only this this field **is not** injected. Other beans and repositories works perfectly fine.

Couldn't be a problem because parent class is an abstract class?

Comment: annotate the Implementation of KeyRecordRepository with @Component

Comment: `KeyRecordRepository` has no implementation.

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseKeyService must be annotated with @Component to be a Spring managed bean.

Comment: I have an annotation `@Service` - forgot to mention, added.

Comment: Do you have @EnableAutoConfiguration in your Spring Boot main class?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related with having 2 beans for class DatabaseKeyService. One from configuration class - @Bean annotation and second from @Service annotation.

Probably when you remove

```
@Bean
    public KeyService keyService() {
        return new DatabaseKeyService();
    }
```

injecting with @Service will be work.

If you want use @Bean you must add KeyRecordRepository. I prefer using constructor injection so firstly create it in DatabaseKeyService

```
public DatabaseKeyService(KeyRecordRepository keyRecordRepository) {
   this.keyRecordRepository = keyRecordRepository;
}
```

Then in your configuration file

```
//other
@Autowired
    private KeyRecordRepository keyRecordRepository;
@Bean
    public KeyService keyService() {
        return new DatabaseKeyService(keyRecordRepository);
    }
```